# How to call an Httprequest parameter from a c# method

Tags: c#

I have below method which I am trying to call from an Azure Function. I am passing a URL but I get error as cannot convert string to Http request.
My question is how can I modify my method here so that I pass a url and "name" as a parameter to the url from my Run() method to Proxyrequest?

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProxyRequest(HttpRequest req)
            {
                var path = req.Path;
                var query = req.QueryString;
                var token = await GetOauthToken();
                var url = $"{_baseURL}{path}{query.ToUriComponent()}";
    
                HttpResponseMessage response = req.Method switch
                {
                    "GET" => await client.GetAsync(url),
                    "POST" => await client.PostAsync(url, ((Func<StreamContent>)(() =>
                    {
                        var content = new StreamContent(req.Body);
                        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", req.ContentType ?? "application/json");
                        return content;
                    }))()),
                    _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"Method {req.Method} is not supported"),
                };
                return response;
            }
    
            [FunctionName("Function1")]
            public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
                [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
                ILogger log)
            {
                log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    
                string name = req.Query["name"];
                string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
                HttpClient myReq = new HttpClient();
                name = name ?? data?.name;
                
                await ProxyRequest("https://localhost:8080");// trying to call the method here
                
    
                string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                    ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                    : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";
    
                return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
            }
```

Comment: Well `ProxyRequest` accepts an `HttpRequest` not a `string`. If you want to pass a `string` such as `name` then you would need to modify the signature and implementation of `ProxyRequest`. I have to say that your goal isn't super clear.

Comment: The `ProxyRequest` needs `HttpRequest` object. but it is not only limited to name and url of the request... it also uses `Method`, `Body` etc properties of `req` object in it. So it will be easier of your to create an object of `HttpRequest` in Run method and pass it to the `ProxyRequest` method. Do you know how `HttpRequest` class look like?

Comment: so exactly thats what i am looking for , I will need to create a ahttprequest with Url and a parameter name="" and pass it to ProxyRequest(). Can you show Httprequest sample and post it as answer here